# Do immigration officers check if i'm working or studying or unemployed?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, philippines, officials, proof-of-employment

Is immigration officer going to check if I'm working, studying or unemployed?

I'm a Moroccan citizen and I'm planning to visit the Philippines (visa free for a stay up 30 days).

And my question is does the immigration officer check if I'm working, studying or unemployed?
And if I'm working, do I need to provide my working certificate? I'm a self-employed barber/hairdresser so I don't have a boss who can sign anything for me.
 Also, because people pay me in cash, I have no proof of where the money in my bank account came from.

Comment: Do you make enough money to owe income tax? If so, a copy of your last tax return may be useful.

Answer (score 4):

The immigration officer may question your reason for entering the country. He may also enquire about your situation in your home country. This helps him understand whether you are likely to breach your entry conditions, by working or staying more than thirty days.

You should answer all questions honestly. Most of the time a short interview will be enough for entry. Sometimes the immigration officer will not ask you anything at all and will simply stamp your passport.

However, if the officer becomes suspicious you may be asked to go through a longer interview and provide proof of your situation.

Comment: what if im unemployed but I have enough money in hand ( cash ) and also in my bank ( with proof ) but I can't provide a working certificate.
I do work but I work for my self, I don't work in a company or anything that can give me a certificate. is that will be aproblem?

Comment: Usually not but they may ask for provenance of funds.

Comment: if they ask for provenance of funds, is it enough to tell me where/what I work without providing a working certificate?

Comment: @reda If you work for yourself, you are "self-employed" and not "unemployed". A "working certificate" is not a normal thing, I have never heard of it.

Comment: @Calchas so you mean it's fine if I don't bring a working certificate?

Comment: You can provide alternate documents. Invoices paid by your clients/customers, earnings from the lands you earn, etc. you just need to provide that you have enough funds, and how they were earned.

Comment: @AyeshK that's the problem, how they were earned.

Comment: I'm a freelancer, with no salary slips and stuff. But I always keep a few invoices and a clean bank account. Never had issues with a visa.

Comment: @AyeshK The country I want to visit doesn't require a visa, I'm afraid from the immigration officer

Comment: @reda This is the best answer I can give you now without knowing why you are afraid. I think there is something important about your work that you aren't telling us. You don't have to tell us—it's private information of course, but I cannot improve my answer without knowing what it is.

Comment: @Calchas It's not that im hiding it. I'm working as a coiffure here in Morocco, I also have a certificate that I'm a coiffure, but I can't provide a proof that the money I earned are from my job, because here in Morocco people pay by cash, not from bank to bank or whtever. they just hand you cash in hand